# Using approximations & the laws of log to perform this calculation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have to use the given approximation and the laws of logarithms to simplify this calculation:

> $\sqrt{1.44}$ ; log $1.728 ≈ 0.23754$

I started off with using **log** on $\sqrt{1.44}$:

> log($\sqrt{1.44}$)
>
> log($1.44^{1 \over 2})$
>
> $0.07918$
>
> = log $1.2$

Now, I'm not sure what I can do with log $1.2$ and log $1.728$ so that I can get the textbook answer of $1.2$.

Comment: Hint. $1.44 = 1.2^2$ and $1.728 = 1.2^3$

Comment: @stevengregory I realize that by dividing $1.738$ by $1.44$ I'd get $1.2$. So I did $0.23754 \over 0.15836$ = $log 1.2$ (the logs of $1.738$ and $1.44$) and I used the power law of logs to get $10^{0.23754 \over 0.15836}$ = $1.2$, however, this isn't true when I calculated this into my calculator?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$1728=12^3\iff 1.728=\dfrac{1728}{1000}=\left(\dfrac{12}{10}\right)^3$$

The problem is reduced to putting in the numbers in $\log(\sqrt{1.44})=\log(1.2)=1/3\cdot\log(1.728)$. Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

$\log 1.2 = \dfrac 13 \log(1.2^3) = \dfrac 13 \log 1.728  \approx 0.07918$

according to Wolfram|Alpha $10^{0.0798} = 1.199997\dots$